# Label are under the node's circle Gephi

Tags: gephi

I have an issue with the latest version of Gephi. In the start, it was working correctly. In the overview tab, it's working perfectly. The labels are shown over the circle as follows.

[image: Network Visualization in the overview tab]

But, in the preview tab, it's not working. The labels are shown under the circle as follows.

[image: Network Visualization in the preview tab]

I need to visualize the lebels over the circle as presented in the overview tabl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels like the order of renderers has been changed and labels are rendered before nodes. Try restoring the renderers order:
[image]